# Compiling error with boost with mingw

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile the following program with boost/asio.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(){
  boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting the following linker errors

```
C:\Users\...\ccsKX5WE.o:myprogram.cpp:(.text+0x136)undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:\Users\...\ccsKX5WE.o:myprogram.cpp:(.text+0x140)undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/mingw/bin/.../ld.exe: C:\Users\...\ccsKx5WE.o: bad reloc address 0xe in section `.text$_|N5boost6system14error_categoryD2Ev]'
collect2.exe@ error: ld return 1 exit status
```

I used mingw as such:

```
g++ -IC:\boost\boost_1_59_0 -o myprogram.exe -LC:\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib -lboost_system-mgw48-1_59 myprogram.cpp
```

I've used all the different versions of libboost_systems flags such as 
lboost_system-mgw48-1_59.a
lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_59.a
etc
and all together but nothing worked.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Order matters for linkage. Put `-lboost_system-mgw48-1_59` as the last item in your compiler command line.

Comment: I tried reordering the command but I still get undefined reference errors.
g++ -IC:\boost\boost_1_59_0 myprogram.cpp -o myprogram.exe -LC:\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib   -lboost_system-mgw48-1_59

Comment: I managed to find out what's wrong. I had to add -lwsock32 at the end

Comment: You should write an appropriate answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the command.

First, as  πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned in the comments, the -lboost_system-mgw48-1_59 flag has to be after the object files.

Secondly, since I was using windows, I needed to add -lwsock32 as well.

```
g++ -IC:\boost\boost_1_59_0 myprogram.cpp -o myprogram.exe - LC:\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib -lboost_system-mgw48-1_59 –lwsock32
```